# Emulator via LAN

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is that possible to do this . We are running android emulator in desktop (ubuntu 18) and we need to run the android studio project from our laptop (ubuntu 14) then connect with emulator from desktop . All laptop and desktop are connected with same network

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the adb over wifi method described in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)? It uses ip adresses and port numbers so I guess it will work with an emulator on a different pc if they're both on the same network as well.